# SVN move a local working sub-dir containing some unversioned files

Tags: svn

I have a structure a bit like

```
/work_dir
 /resources
  /sounds
  /game_sounds
```

I want to move `game_sounds` into `sounds` without losing history, but it contains some unversioned files which need to stay unversioned.

Is there a SVN command that can do this in one operation, if so what would I do... and if not what would I do then?

(using svn client 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to do the move server-side:

```
svn mv http://server/repos/work_dir/resources/game_sounds
       http://server/repos/work_dir/resources/sounds/game_sounds
```

Next time you update it'll move the folder and all of the versioned files in your working copy too. It will leave the unversioned files in the old game_sounds folder so you'll have to move those across manually.

It'd be safest to commit and outstanding changes you have in game_sounds first - I'm not sure if you'd end up with regular conflicts or tree conflicts otherwise.